# I want to use 2 formula in one cell. If one formula returns 0 value, I want to use the other formular to return value

Tags: excel, if-statement, google-sheets

what I want to perform is: 
if "SUMIF('NJ'!A:A,C3,'NJ'!I:I)≠0", return the value of the "SUMIF('NJ'!A:A,C3,'NJ'!I:I)"
if "SUMIF('NJ'!A:A,C3,'NJ'!I:I)=0", I want to use this formula "SUMIF('QJ'!A:A,C5,'QJ'!AC:AC)" to return the value. 
How do I put all this formula in one single cell? 
I just can't find the right answer on google, please help me ㅠ

Comment: Seems like you answered your own question (`If This Then That`) i.e. use `=IF`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this

Logic:

```
=IF(1;0;IF(1;2))
```

Your case, given your text description:

```
=IF(SUMIF('NJ'!A:A,C3,'NJ'!I:I)<>0;SUMIF('NJ'!A:A,C3,'NJ'!I:I);
IF(SUMIF('NJ'!A:A,C3,'NJ'!I:I)=0;SUMIF('QJ'!A:A,C5,'QJ'!AC:AC)))
```

Comment: I think your header line for the post actually says that the =0 should come first and then evaluate <> 0... Just change place of the formulas.

Comment: it's working now! Thanks a lot~ I wish the formula can be more shortened. but this is great